# Populating values for pojo according to environment variables in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class where I'm mapping the properties defined in the application file. However if an environment variable like enabled is defined, I want to set two fields to a default value defined in other environment variables. How can I do that. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "school.students")
@Data
public class SchoolStudents {

    private List<Details> details;

    @Data
    public static class Details {
        private String name;
        private String class;
        private String floor;
        private int rollNo;|

    }

}
```

Here is my application.yaml:

```
school:
  student:
    details:
    - name: Aaraon
      class: Sixth
      floor: First
      rollNo: 70
    - name: Lisa
      class: Third
      floor: Second
      rollNo: 102
```

So in the above case, if an environment variable enabled is set to true, I want to pick up the class & floor from the environment variables already present in the system. The environment variables would be 102_floor,102_class,70_floor,70_class. So for Lisa, the 102_class & 102_floor variables values need to be populated.

Comment: Why are you not using env specific application file to override the values in default application file?

Comment: can you give me an example of that

Comment: How's your application file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment` bean for this case, so you can inject the bean in your class which will have this logic

```
public class SomeServiceOrLogicClass {
     @Autowired
     private Environment env;
     
     @Autowired
     private SchoolStudents students;

     public void someLogicFunction() {
          schoolStudents.forEach(student -> {
             for(Detail d : student.getDetails()) {
                System.out.println(env.getProperty(d.getRollNo() + "_floor"));
           // Similar for class thing     
             }
          })
          
     }
}
```

*Notice that I have used literal value of env variable as you pasted in your question, if you want to use floor and class value from properties also then you can just concat that instead of floor/class in loop*

**The logic function is to just give you idea, you may use your logic**

Comment: The environment variable would be something like {rollNo}_floor so I have to fetch it based on the roll no in the application properties file.

Comment: I didn't get you, what is the env into your use case? is roll no an environment or it is a value? Please add more info to your question.

Comment: Actually there might be different environment variables for floor & class. So each would be appended with a roll no. For example it'll be rollNo11_floor, rollNo12_floor & so on. I need to fetch the env variable based on the rollNo given in the application properties file.

Comment: I am still not getting what you are trying to do, please update your question with examples and explanation of use case.

Comment: Edited the question,let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: I have changed my answer, please check if thats what you desired.